# How to modify this URL in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to modify URL with a check.

1. If there exists experiment as second folder, then do this

   {site}.com/dashboard/experiment/closed/.../

   to

   {site}.com/experiment/closed/.../
2. If no experiment found in path, then don't do anything. For eg

   {site}.com/dashboard/ex-view/closed/.../

How do I achive this using htaccess. I'm using Laravel 5.1.

This is what I tried but it doesn't meet the second condition.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^experiment/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: So then how did it work out?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this rule in the .htaccess in the root. The should only affect URL with `experiment` as the second folder.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^.+/experiment/(.*)$ /experiment/$1 [L,NC,R]
```